# Paper Folding to produce an equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry, origami

A rectangular strip of paper edge $AC$ is first folded in half making fold crease through mid-point $M$ and again bent folded along a new line through $C$ adjusted such that corner $A$ falls on divider $MB$. Show that triangle $ABC$ is equilateral.

EDIT1:

Rajendra Kumar makes a full [Icosahedron](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dj6s1kr3GuM) repeated in this way!

[image: Origami]

Comment: By construction of $B$, $BC = AC$. By symmetry wrt line $MB$, $AB = CB$... Am I missing something???

Comment: Nothing, :) except that it's too simple!

Comment: Related: [This response](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2781359/409) which offers the answer "tetrahedron" to the question "Is there a shape that can be wrapped perfectly?"; the wrapping technique involves this folding construction of the equilateral triangle. My comment there notes that U.S. dollar bills are just-about perfect for folding such tetrahedra.

Comment: Even an irregular/smaller octahedron possible by folding dollar bill into triangles, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an interesting problem. Thank you for posting it.

[image].

Construct $BD$ perpendicular to one edge of the paper
$$ BD = MC = \frac{1}{2}AC = \frac{1}{2}BC$$
It follows that 
$$\angle BCD = 30^\circ\\ \angle MCB = 60^\circ $$
From the condition that you give,
$$AC = BC$$
Therefore $\Delta ACB$ is an equilateral triangle.